# Batch script- b was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

```
for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %a in (tmp.txt) do @echo %b > tmp1.txt
```

When I run the following bat file, this is throwing this message.

```
D:\>sample.bat
```

> b was unexpected at this time.

Comment: You should take care which tag you select. `"delims= "` is default and doesn't need to be expressed. In a batch file the percent signs of the for variables have to be doubled (single ones only if in cmd line). `for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%a in (tmp.txt) do @echo %%b > tmp1.txt`

Comment: Thank you LotPings, this helped..!